# while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) + JAVASCRIPT error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem with some code. The proram allows me to copy from one lick one password that is sought on my BDDMysql. I have a script that allows me to copy the content of the html tag `<P>`, with a specific ID. All of that i got it inside of a `while(mysqli_fetch_array($result))`. So the problem is, when i click for copy one password, only i get the first one of the bdd copied on the clipboard.

```
<?php

$egest='SELECT * FROM gestion';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$egest);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//echo $row['subcat_nombre'];
?>

<script>
    function copyToClipboard(element) {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
    }
</script>

<table class="estilo-ps">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="td-tit"><b><?php echo $row['gest_nombre'] ?></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-borders">
    <th class="th-border-cent">Contrasenya</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-borders">
    <td class="td-border-cent">
        <center>
            <p hidden="hidden" id="p1"><?php echo $row['gest_contra']; ?></p><br>
            <p>clic per copiar la contrasenya</p>
            <img src="img/key.png" class="copy" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')"/>
        </center>
    </td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to define a function in a loop. A function can only have one definition, you're just replacing it each time.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have multiple `id="p1"`. `$(element)` will always return the first one, not the one in the same row that the user clicked on.

Comment: You have a `<table>` tag but no `</table>`. Do you really want to create a separate table for each row that the query returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have duplicate IDs. Use a class instead of an ID. Then use the appropriate DOM selection function to find the element with that class next to the clicked element.

Also, take the function out of the loop, it doesn't need to be redefined for each row.

```
<script>
    function copyToClipboard(img) {
      var $element = $(img).siblings(".p1");
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($element.text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
    }
</script>

<?php

$egest='SELECT * FROM gestion';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$egest);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//echo $row['subcat_nombre'];
?>


<table class="estilo-ps">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="td-tit"><b><?php echo $row['gest_nombre'] ?></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-borders">
    <th class="th-border-cent">Contrasenya</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-borders">
    <td class="td-border-cent">
        <center>
            <p hidden="hidden" class="p1"><?php echo $row['gest_contra']; ?></p><br>
            <p>clic per copiar la contrasenya</p>
            <img src="img/key.png" class="copy" onclick="copyToClipboard(this)"/>
        </center>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok taking notes for the next time. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$egest='SELECT * FROM gestion';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$egest);
?>

<script>
    function copyToClipboard(element) {
      var $temp = $("<input>");
      $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      $temp.remove();
    }
</script>

<table class="estilo-ps">
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//echo $row['subcat_nombre'];
?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="td-tit"><b><?php echo $row['gest_nombre'] ?></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-borders">
    <th class="th-border-cent">Contrasenya</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr-borders">
    <td class="td-border-cent">
        <center>
            <p hidden="hidden" id="p1"><?php echo $row['gest_contra']; ?></p><br>
            <p>clic per copiar la contrasenya</p>
            <img src="img/key.png" class="copy" onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')"/>
        </center>
    </td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

You are trying to loop the script. Script should be declared only once.
Move your while loop after `<table>` .